# How can I extract only the transaction input data value of geth in web3.js?

Tags: web3js

```
 var tto_count = document.getElementById("to_count");
   //var transaction = web3.eth.getTransactionFromBlock(1865, 0).input;
   //var transaction = web3.eth.getTransactionFromBlock(1865, 0).then(console.log);
   var transaction = web3.eth.getTransactionFromBlock(1865, 0);
   //tto_count.value = web3.eth.toString(transaction);
   tto_count.value = JSON.stringify(transaction);
```

**This is the source code I've failed so far.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using web3 v1.2.xx the call is async and either you use promises or `await`.

It will return a [transaction object](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.9/web3-eth.html#eth-gettransaction-return), the input field contains what you were looking for.

```
web3.eth.getTransactionFromBlock(1865, 0)
.then(function (tx) {
  console.log(tx.input)
});
```

Comment: Oh my god... Thank you... Thank you so much!!